# Policy for restricting access to an entire S3 bucket except for a single directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My goal is to restrict ALL access to an entire S3 bucket (users should get access denied when entering the object URL) except for one single directory (lets call it XX) and all its content (images) - that needs to be available to anyone accessing these images from anywhere.

I tried to use this Policy (as well as other policies) but unfortunately it restricted ANY access to this S3 bucket (Editing, viewing, changing policy and such... I can't even delete this bucket now only with root account).

Now, I understand that Denying 's3:*' made these problems but how can I overcome this?

I just want people to be denied if they try to access the objects in this bucket expect for the assets folder.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyAllBucketAccess",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::XX",
            "arn:aws:s3:::XX/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAssetsAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::XX/assets/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Would love to get your help here.. Thank you guys.

Comment: They're denied by default. You only need to explicitly deny access within the bucket policy if you're trying to prevent IAM roles/users who have IAM permission to access the contents.

Comment: @jarmod I am trying to prevent any client from the internet accessing these S3 urls, not IAM roles/users. (expect the 'assets' folder ofc)

Comment: IAM users come via the internet too, but I think by "client from the internet" you mean an unauthenticated client, presenting an HTTP(S) URL for an object. Simply remove the `Deny` statement from your bucket policy. The default policy is to deny access, and your single `Allow` policy allows unauthenticated users to get, put, and delete all objects in the `XX` bucket below the prefix of `assets/`. Note that it's unusual, and dangerous, to allow unauthenticated users to put and delete arbitrary objects so you might need to re-think that part of the policy.